# Get variable from nested macro into "outer" macro by calling/running other workbook/file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a main macro (macro1) running smaller macros (macroA and macroB) in other **.xlam* or **.xslm* files .

I need, besides the little macros (A+B) doing their job, specific variables and their values in the "outer" macro (macro1) for further use in its code.

Is there a way of passing variable values from within the macros A+B to macro1?

**Background:**
I know that declaring a `Public Variable` can be used in different macros. I also know how to pass variables or their values from one macro to a following one. But (given my example below) how can I give a variable "back" to macro1?

**Example (1)** of passing variables in between `Subs` without calling other workbooks/files (working):

```vb
Public wbA as Workbook
Public wbB as Workbook
Sub MySubRoutine()
    Set wbA = Workbooks.Open("C:\file.xlsx")
    Set wbB = Workbooks.Open("C:\file2.xlsx")
    OtherSubRoutine
End Sub
Sub OtherSubRoutine()
    Debug.Print wbA.Name
End Sub
```

> OUTPUT: file.xlsx

**Example (2)** of passing variables from called `Sub` to another from other workbook/file (non-working):

```vb
Public count As Integer
Sub macro1()
    Run file.xlam! & macroB, argument1, argument2
    Debug.Print count  'second print
End Sub
Sub macroB(argument1, argument2)
    'code that does something
    count = 5
    Debug.Print count  'first print
End Sub
```

> OUTPUT first print:  5
> OUTPUT second print: 0

Code finishes without errors or debug messages. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Didn't you find some time to check the solution I suggested? If yes, didn't it clarify your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should transform the `Sub` in a function (able to return something) and call it in a little different way:

1. Put the next function in workbook 1 (for exemplification, I used 'PERSONAL.XLSB'):

```
Function GiveMeFive(x As Long, y As Long) As Long
    Debug.Print x + y 'not important, ONLY TO SEE IT WORKING IN immediate Window
    GiveMeFive = 5
End Function
```

2. Call it from another workbook in this way:

```
Sub testFunctionWithArgsOtherWb()
   Dim x As Long
   x = Run("PERSONAL.XLSB!" & "GiveMeFive", 4, 3)
   Debug.Print x
End Sub
```

It will return in Immediate Window: 7 (from the function itself) and 5, what the function returned when it was called...

**Second version**:

If you don't like functions, you can return a `Public` variable value using a `Sub`, in this way:

1. Create a `Public` variable in another workbook (also used Personal.xlsb), but **in ThisWorkbook code module**:

```
Public MyVar As Long
```

2. Create such a `Sub` in a standard module:

```
Sub MyMacro(x As Long, y As Long)
   ThisWorkbook.MyVar = x * y
End Sub
```

3. Call the `Sub` from a different workbook and read the global variable, modified by the called `Sub`:

```
Sub testValFromOtherWB()
   Dim x As Long
    Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!" & "MyMacro", 4, 3
    x = Workbooks("PERSONAL.XLSB").MyVar
    Debug.Print x
End Sub
```

Please, test them and send some feedback.

Comment: @Capt.Krusty Didn't you find some time to test the above suggestion? If tested, didn't they clarify what you needed to understand?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the point I was missing by calling from another `Sub` was to declare the variable as the result for the running `Sub`/`Function`. The part `x = Run("PERSONAL.XLSB!" & "GiveMeFive", 4, 3)` was the part that helped finding my problem, thank!

Comment: @Capt.Krusty I would you to start using functions. No need of any variable in the other workbook and if you need to use the result in many places, try creating a `Public` variable in the calling workbook...